# Gluon Cloud/Cloudlink File Storage

Tags: javafx, gluon, gluon-mobile

Is it possible to store a file such as an audio file, or create directories with files in them using Gluon Cloud or Gluon Cloudlink?

Comment: Do you mean you want `remote file storage`? [Currently](http://docs.gluonhq.com/connect/1.1.0/#_supported_data_types) you can just send primitive or properties of those primitives.

Comment: Yes, If remote file storage is not supported, can I use the map type and register the file name as a Key and an array of bytes as the Value?

Comment: That could work if you encode the byte array into String. Be aware of possible issues if you intent to stream big amount of data.